# Cambiar barra de progreso(seleccion)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando de realizar una pagina, la cual contiene como una barra de seleccion, y un boton tipo como para activar o desactivar, el problema es que no se la forma de realizarlo, no se si habra alguna etiqueta para hacerlo, ya que no encuentro ninguna.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la barra verde, el "boton" que esta alado de monthly Billing.

Comment: Y cuál es el código asociado a esta captura de pantalla? Has intentado algo en JS para conseguir ésto? (pues, pusiste esa etiqueta, así que algo tendrás por ahí en JS)

Comment: la captura es solo el ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer, que es la barra verde y el boton, de lo cual no se como hacerlo. Y la etiqueta de javascript, pense que talves se usa para realizarla.